# when I use my microwave I can see and hear Sparks coming from behind my refrigerator. What's going on? What can I do to fix it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

---

> Dude I don't know I just want to know why when I use my microwave the outlet behind my refrigerator starts sparking and I can see and hear it and that's the only time it does it the only time the microwave and refrigerator on separate outlets but they are in the same room directly across from each other but I've been here for a year and a half and had never had a problem like that now the upstairs in this townhouse that I rent my two kids room the electric goes in and out because they did not wire it correctly so I have to fix it every so often because the socket where they had the two bedrooms powered to they have that Master outlet being powered by the light switch so the outlet that powers the two bedrooms is in the bathroom upstairs and that outlet is powered by the light switch right next to it now there's a wire going from the light switch to the outlet but here's the thing when that wire goes to the outlet it goes to a spot on the outlet where there's already a wire so there's two wires on one screw of an outlet so every so often I have to go in and make sure that the wire is tight and where it needs to be or my kids don't have electric in the room could that be why this is happening downstairs in the kitchen with the sparks of my refrigerator outlet

---

Comment: As a renter, tell your landlord to have an electrician come and check it out, it must be an electrician in a rental.  Sparks are bad, as in burning the building down.

Comment: What did you copy/paste this from adding some punctuation and formatting would make it much easier to read because you know dude sentences and stuff an if youre renting its def on the landlord to fix it

Answer (score 5):

Since you **rent**, you call your landlord and they send a **licensed electrician** (any other response such as an unlicensed handyman or maintenance guy, or the landlord themselves, or you working on it yourself is a code violation in the USA, anyway; not knowing where you are located.)

Meanwhile, don't use the microwave.

*If the landlord refuses, this becomes more of a legal than home improvement question. It's a legitimate reason to break the lease and move out before the building burns down, or you hire an electrician and take them to court for the cost, or various other options, none of which are really home improvement.*